# Getting a List of Instances for events using Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a list of instances for events using Microsoft graph api.

However the query I'm using isn't returning the correct results

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/AAMkAGE1NzYzMjQzLTUxYjgtNGRkNy05OWQwLWI5NDg4ZTllMmY1ZABGAAAAAABQWKBNQwTYQJetvDXHaTj5BwAnoxmHMuwhS5hpU9enDX9FAAAAAAENAAAnoxmHMuwhS5hpU9enDX9FAABDXZWWAAA=/instances
```

Response that I get:

```
{
    "error": 
    {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidParameter",
        "message": "This request requires a time window specified by the query string parameters StartDateTime and EndDateTime.",
        "innerError": 
        {
            "request-id": "e434261b-c32f-48b4-b21d-3e1beab6d525",
            "date": "2015-12-09T21:42:34"
        }
    }
}
```

So I tried adding in some dateTimes

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/AAMkAGE1NzYzMjQzLTUxYjgtNGRkNy05OWQwLWI5NDg4ZTllMmY1ZABGAAAAAABQWKBNQwTYQJetvDXHaTj5BwAnoxmHMuwhS5hpU9enDX9FAAAAAAENAAAnoxmHMuwhS5hpU9enDX9FAABDXZWTAAA=/instances(startDateTime=2015-12-12T19:38:00+00:00, endDateTime=2015-12-12T19:45:00+00:00)
```

And the Response I get is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
        <title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--
            body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
            fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
            h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
            h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
            h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
            #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
            background-color:#555555;}
            #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
            .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
            -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Server Error</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="content-container">
                <fieldset>
                    <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
                    <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the correct syntax for this query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StartDateTime and EndDateTime should be passed as query parameters, e.g. GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/id/instances?startDateTime=2015-12-12T19:38:00%2B00:00&endDateTime=2015-12-12T19:45:00%2B00:00

Comment: I got the following response https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/AAMkAGE1NzYzMjQzLTUxYjgtNGRkNy05OWQwLWI5NDg4ZTllMmY1ZABGAAAAAABQWKBNQwTYQJetvDXHaTj5BwAnoxmHMuwhS5hpU9enDX9FAAAAAAENAAAnoxmHMuwhS5hpU9enDX9FAABDXZWYAAA=/instances?startDateTime=2015-12-15T17:00:00%2B00:00&endDateTime=2015-12-15T18:00:00%2B00:00 "ErrorInvalidParameter",
    "message": "The value '2015-12-15T17:00:00%2b00:00' of parameter 'StartDateTime' is invalid."

Comment: The following format is working: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/[id]/instances?startDateTime=2015-12-07T16:00:00.0000000&endDateTime=2015-12-07T16:00:00.0000000`

Comment: I put it in exactly that way but for some reason I keep getting an invalid parameter error:  '2015-12??-12T16:00:00%2b00:00' of parameter 'StartDateTime' is invalid. Notice the question marks after the month.

Comment: The query parameter values need to be url encoded. When using the API Exlorer app (https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net) and Fiddler it was enough for me to replace + with %2B, but it would depend on what you're using to send the request. Try with fully url encoded values: startDateTime=2015-12-15T17%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00&endDateTime=2015-12-15T18%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00